# How to see test cases results running using test agents in real time with TFS 2018?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, microsoft-test-manager

Since MTM lab management is deprecated in TFS 2018 and we are setting up test agents as part of build definition ,How can we see test cases results in real time ?
For example if user wants to know how many test cases are in progress ,passed,failed.

In MTM we can see while running test cases using TCM.exe till tfs 2017

Could any one please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately real-time output for tests is not supported for now.

There are some similar user voices submitted to suggest the feature:

- [Provide VStest.console.exe \ Test Explorer Real Time Test Execution
  Status DURING Test Execution](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/7660938-provide-vstest-console-exe-test-explorer-real-ti)
- [That I could see the reports that I see in the MTM tool, from a
  Confluence Page (real time updated info on testing status).](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/33506494-that-i-could-see-the-reports-that-i-see-in-the-mtm)

You can go and vote them up or submit a new user voice to suggest the feature again to achieve the feature in future release.

Similar threads for your reference:

- [Real time status/logs of test execution not available on VSTS
  console](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3492)
- [Real time logs/stats of unit test execution on VSTS console](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3986)